# git - trying to exclude certain files but want to add everything else

Tags: git

I am looking to add an entire website to a repository, but I want it to ignore several files.

So in my cloned folder I went to the exclude file and added the filename which is located in the root of the site.

E.g.

/myrootfile.php

I then try `git add *` to add everything, however Im getting the following warning...

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
myrootfile.php
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

I am wondering how should I still add everything else but simply ignore this file?

Thank you

Comment: As you have figured out yourself, `git add .` is what you are looking for.  Maybe just answer your own question, so future visitors can quickly find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell is expanding your glob pattern, so when you run

```
git add *
```

it is as though you had invoked

```
git add myrootfile.php this.php that.php the-other.html
```

Hence poor git’s confusion because you say you want to ignore it but then explicitly add it.

In your site root, run the following instead

```
git add .
```

The dot refers to the current directory, into which git then descends recursively.

Answer (score 0):

`git add .` worked, I am unsure why but this resolves the issue, after that `git add *` seems to work, so im assuming it adds the required .gitignore file.